# Jetpack Compose: fillMaxWidth() for Icon in jetpack Compose doesn't work

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I want to try to enlarge the icon inside the box to be filling the parent width, which normally can be approached with fillMaxWidth, but the Icon didn't react, only the boundary/the imaginary boundary of the icon enlarged to the parent width.

original:
[image: before fillmaxwidth]

after:
[image: after fillmaxwidth]

Comment: Post your code instead of images

Answer (score 0):

Without specifing a `size` modifier in the `Icon` there is a default size of `24.dp`

Internal `Icon` code:

```
private fun Modifier.defaultSizeFor(painter: Painter) =
    this.then(
        if (painter.intrinsicSize == Size.Unspecified || painter.intrinsicSize.isInfinite()) {
            DefaultIconSizeModifier //24.dp
        } else {
            Modifier
        }
    )
```

Use something like:

```
Icon(Icons.Filled.Delete, "", Modifier.size(32.dp))
```

With and without `size` modifier:

[image]